# Populating items in select2 input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have the need to work with tags in my Laravel application using Bootstrap 4.

In the create views, I have a 'multiple select dropdown' using the select2.min.js library:

[image]

In the controller I have:

```
$tags = Tag::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
```

In the CREATE view, I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label" for="tags">Tags:  (*)</label>
  <select class="form-control tag-multiple" name="beeritem_tags[]" multiple="multiple">
      @foreach($tags as $tag)
          <option value="{{$tag->id}}">{{$tag->tag_name}}</option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

and I have the following JS code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.tag-multiple').select2();
   });
</script>
```

Now I also have an EDIT form, which allows a user to add or remove tags. So I need the input field to be pre-populated with the tags for that item. So the moment someone opens the edit form, he should see the screenshot above (which contains the items the user selected during the create process).

How can I populate the input element with the tags?

Comment: I don't get the issue. What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it. You are not retrieving the general tags.

First you need to retrieve all your tags

```
$tags = Tag::all();
```

Then get the Authenticated user's selected tags.

```
$user_tags = Tag::where('user_id', Auth::id())->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

On your blade you need to loop through the general tags then checked if a **tag ID** is in array of **$user_tags**.
Something like the below code.

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label" for="tags">Tags:  (*)</label>
  <select class="form-control tag-multiple" name="beeritem_tags[]" multiple="multiple">
      @foreach($tags as $tag)
          <option value="{{$tag->id}}" {{ in_array($tag->id, $user_tags) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$tag->tag_name}}</option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

If you get the idea you'll figure out the solution or you might modify the provided code a little.